# Is there a way to override the default GitLab CI AutoDevOps templates?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

I am running my GitLab CI pipelines in an offline environment with none of my repositories containing the pipeline YAML files. Due to the sheer number of repositories I enabled AutoDevOps to use a baseline image until I can define pipelines for each specific repository as necessary, however, the application dependencies and pipeline images cannot be downloaded. [I have a means to resolve this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#use-images-hosted-in-a-local-docker-registry), but it requires configuration in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file meaning the default AutoDevOps templates cannot be used and I have to make changes in every single repository, defeating the point of enabling AutoDevOps in the first place.

Is there a way to override the default AutoDevOps templates with my own?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#customizing-gitlab-ciyml) :

> Auto DevOps is completely customizable because the Auto DevOps
> template is just an implementation of a .gitlab-ci.yml file.

So AutoDevOps pipelines are only `.gitlab-ci.yml` files and you need to include them to overrides jobs and anything in this pipeline. You need to include a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to override the default.

AutoDevOps is useful even if you include a ci file because it add a lot of jobs without writing them.

Comment: This works if I add `.gitlab-ci.yml` files to each repository, however, I wish to make use of defaults so all my projects will run in GitLab CI as-is without necessitating a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: Yes but you need to add a .gitlab-ci.yml file to customize the AutoDevOps template.